# Replace html element with another element/text. Problem in the Source Code

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, wordpress

Im working on it from many many days (I'm not a developer).
I want to replace HTML element with another element/text (p to h1 in the page-id-27), have tried 3 different solutions and are working in inspection mode and 'visually', but the source code doesn't change.
I really need that the source code can change too.
Is this idea possible? Is something wrong here?
Many thanks

HTML:

```
<p class="title_banner"><strong>Sport</strong></p>
```

3 Solutions:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var str = '<h1>Sport</h1>';
$('.title_banner').replaceWith(str);
    });
```

```
var e = document.getElementsByClassName('title_banner')[0];
var d = document.createElement('h1');
d.innerHTML = e.innerHTML;
e.parentNode.insertBefore(d, e);
e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
```

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".title_banner").html("<h1>Sport</h1>");
});
});
```

Function

```
function scriptnew(){
wp_register_script('dynamic-title', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/dynamic-title.js', array( 'jquery' ), NULL, false );
if ( is_page('27') ) {
wp_enqueue_script( 'dynamic-title' );
}}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scriptnew', 10 );
```

Comment: Source code can't be changed with javascript. It is what is sent by server

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace element

First get innerHtml from element `p`.

Then create a new element `h1` place the content in the new element.

After this replace element `p` with `h1`

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('title_banner')[0];
var y = x.innerHTML;

var newItem = document.createElement('h1');
newItem.innerHTML = y;

x.parentNode.replaceChild(newItem, x);
```

```html
<p class="title_banner"><strong>Sport</strong></p>
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. Source code can't be changed with javascript. (see comment above).

Comment: Please copy the HTML code from your web page and attach it to your original post